# how to group objects in array that are pointing at eact other

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, each object is pointing at another object in the "related" field.

I need to group the object with the related field so I can output them in groups on my website.

how can I group something like this

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "dog",
    related: "cat",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "cat",
    related: "dog",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "shark",
    related: "whale",
  },
];
```

to this ?

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "dog",
      related: "cat",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "cat",
      related: "dog",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "shark",
      related: "whale",
    },
  ],
];
```

Comment: Please share the code tried so far

Comment: what is the output if we change the `related` animal of `id:2` to `shark`

Answer (score 1):

Here i've tried this. It'll only work for two way binding relations.

```js
const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "dog",
      related: "cat",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "cat",
      related: "dog",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "shark",
      related: "whale",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "whale",
      related: "shark",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "test",
      related: "none",
    },
  ];

  const categoriesData = (data) => {
    const dataObj = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
      if (!obj[item.name]) obj[item.related] = [item];
      else if (obj[item.name] && obj[item.name][0].name === item.related)
        obj[item.name].push(item);
      return obj;
    }, {});
    return Object.values(dataObj);
  };

  console.log(categoriesData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` it:

```js
var data=[ { id: 1, name: "dog", related: "cat", }, { id: 2, name: "cat", related: "dog", }, { id: 3, name: "shark", related: "whale", }];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    const key = [elem.name, elem.related].sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)).join('|');
    acc[key] = [...(acc[key] || []), elem];
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't exactly answer your question, but is more of an "outside the box" solution. your data would be much simpler, straight forward and easy to manage if you simply add a "category" field.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "dog",
    related: "cat",
    category: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "cat",
    related: "dog",
    category: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "shark",
    related: "whale",
    category: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
     name: "whale",
    related: "shark",
    category: 2,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could gather all relations first, then build groups of related values and then map the groups by filtering the data.

This approach works with longer chains of related objects.

```js
function getGroups(k, group) {
    if (seen.has(k)) return;
    seen.add(k);
    group.push(k);
    relations[k].forEach(v => seen.has(v) || getGroups(v, group));
}


var data = [{ id: 1, name: "dog", related: "cat" }, { id: 2, name: "cat", related: "dog" }, { id: 3, name: "shark", related: "whale" }],
    relations = {},
    groups = [],
    seen = new Set,
    result;

data.forEach(({ name, related }) => {
    if (!relations[name]) relations[name] = [];
    relations[name].push(related);
    if (!relations[related]) relations[related] = [];
    relations[related].push(name);
});

Object.keys(relations).forEach(k => {
    let group = [];
    getGroups(k, group);
    if (group.length) groups.push(group);
});

result = groups.map(group => data.filter(({ name }) => group.includes(name)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to create a `Map` holding the animals. Then for each animal in this collection (that is not removed) create a group and remove it from the collection. Find related animals and add them to the same group, also removing them from the collection.

```js
const animals = [
  { id: 1, name: "dog",   related: "cat"   },
  { id: 2, name: "cat",   related: "dog"   },
  { id: 3, name: "shark", related: "whale" },
];

const animalsMap = new Map(animals.map(animal => [animal.name, animal]));
const animalGroups = [];

for (let [,animal] of animalsMap) {
  const group = Array.of(animal);
  
  while (
    animalsMap.delete(animal.name),
    animal = animalsMap.get(animal.related)
  ) {
    group.push(animal);
  }
  
  animalGroups.push(group);
}

console.log(animalGroups);
```